# EA - Table template for single element manipulation

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to design a template that generates a document based on the following Diagram.

[image: Modeling Diagram]

For each System (1 or 2) there is a Chapter, which will be further populated with subchapters for every "Element type C".

Example of chapter structure
[image: Example of chapter structure]

The template I'm using is this one:
[image: Document Template]

And it calls a table:
[image: Table to be filled]

While scripting the fragment of this, for each element type C, I'm checking the connection type ( connection Y) to see if the element is related and can be added to the bottom half of the table. If so, the ID of element Type B is added to an XML structure.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
    function arrange_data_in_xml(objectid) {
    //Get the repository type
    var repotype = Repository.RepositoryType();
    //Create the xml structure
    var xmlDOM = new COMObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0");
    xmlDOM.validateOnParse = false;
    xmlDOM.async = false;
    var node = xmlDOM.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'");
    xmlDOM.appendChild(node);
    var xmlRoot = xmlDOM.createElement("EADATA");
    xmlDOM.appendChild(xmlRoot);
    var xmlDataSet = xmlDOM.createElement("Dataset_0");
    xmlRoot.appendChild(xmlDataSet);
    var xmlData = xmlDOM.createElement("Data");
    xmlDataSet.appendChild(xmlData);

    var part1A = Repository.GetElementSet(sqlquery, 2);
    //Session.Output(part1A.Count)
    //This cycle will iterate over each Element Type B
 
    for (var i = 0; i < part1A.Count; i++) {
        var ElementTypeBrow = ""
        var countElementTypeB = 0;
        Session.Output("DEBUG 0 " + part1A.GetAt(i).ElementID + " -- " + part1A.GetAt(i).Name + " -- " + objectid)
        
        var xmlRow = xmlDOM.createElement("Row");
        xmlData.appendChild(xmlRow);
                
        var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("Object_ID");
        xmlName.text = part1A.GetAt(i).ElementID;
        xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
                
        var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("ElementTypeCName");
        xmlName.text = part1A.GetAt(i).Name;
        xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
        
        for (var k = 0; k < part1A.GetAt(i).TaggedValues.Count; k++) {
            var tv = part1A.GetAt(i).TaggedValues.GetAt(k);     
            if (tv.Name == 'Proprety X') {
                var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("ElementTypeC.TagValue1");
                xmlName.text = tv.Value;
                xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
            } else if (tv.Name == 'Proprety Y') {
                var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("ElementTypeC.TagValue2");
                xmlName.text = tv.Value;
                xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
            }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < part1A.GetAt(i).Connectors.Count; j++) {
            var connector = part1A.GetAt(i).Connectors.GetAt(j);        
            if (connector.Stereotype == 'Connection type Z') {
                var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("ElementTypeC.TagValue3");
                xmlName.text = Repository.GetElementByID(connector.SupplierID).Name;
                xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
            } else if (connector.Stereotype == 'Connection type Y') {
                var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("ElementTypeC.TagValue4");
                xmlName.text = Repository.GetElementByID(connector.ClientID).Name;
                xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
            } else if (connector.Stereotype == 'Connection type X'') {
                var ElementTypeB = Repository.GetElementByID(connector.SupplierID)
                //Check if the ElementTypeB is connected to the current interface           
                if (check_interface(ElementTypeB.ElementID) == objectid) {
                    //Session.Output("DEBUG 1 " + part1A.GetAt(i).Name + " - " + ElementTypeB.Name)
                    var ElementTypeBalias = ""
                    if (ElementTypeB.Alias != "") {ElementTypeBalias = " (" + ElementTypeB.Alias + ")"}
                    ElementTypeBrow = ElementTypeB.Name + ElementTypeBalias + " \n" + ElementTypeBrow
                    countElementTypeB = countElementTypeB + 1           
                }
            }
        }       
        

        //Session.Output("DEBUG 1 " +ElementTypeBrow + " - " + countElementTypeBs + " - " + ElementTypeB.Name)
        var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("ApplicableElementTypeB-Hyperlink");
        if (countElementTypeBs > 1) {
            xmlName.text = ElementTypeBrow.trimStart();
        } else {
            xmlName.text = ElementTypeB.ElementGUID+ElementTypeBrow;            
        }
        xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
    
        }
        
    return xmlDOM.xml;
}
```

The problem that I'm having now is the result list of elements is taken as one, ie all of the elements of the bottom half of the table are as one.
Is there a way to manipulate each element individually (for example create a hyperlink for each entry)?

I've tried to rearrange the XML stucture. But the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments like this expect there contents in the form of a table, with rows and columns.

Currently you are only returning a single row, but somehow you would like to split the different values for `ElementTypeBName-Hyperlink` into different rows.

I think you have two possibilities here:

1. Return each `ElementTypeBName-Hyperlink` element with a different name e.g. **ElementTypeBName-Hyperlink1**, **ElementTypeBName-Hyperlink2**,... and then use each of those in your table template.
   Downside of this approach is that it isn't flexible at all, and only useful if you have more or less the same number of ElementB names.
2. Split your template into two templates. One template for the upper part, and one for the lower part.

Another observation is that you are taking the complicated (and slow) route. For requirements like this, it's much easier to create an SQL template instead of a script template.

Comment: Hi Geert! 
Thank you for your fast response. I will try the two-template approach. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi Geert!, I´ve been trying to implement the split approach with a Jscript for the top and bottom half of the table. But I still didn´t get the intended output, in your comment you refer a SQL template, I´m currently using a SQL Query to identify the Type-C elements related to a given System and extract the Type B that are connected to that. To my understanding, I don´t think it is possible to do that with SQL. I´m I wrong?  Is that possible?

Comment: Sure that's possible with an SQL template. If it's in the database, you can query it.